# HttpAsyncClient direct memory leak?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, apache-httpcomponents, apache-httpasyncclient

I use Apache httpasyncclient 4.1, in jconsole, I found that direct memory is continuously growing, I tried force gc, do not work.

And what confused me is that I do not use DirectByteBufferAllocator.

```
ManagedNHttpClientConnectionFactory connFactory = new ManagedNHttpClientConnectionFactory(null,
            null, HeapByteBufferAllocator.INSTANCE);
connManager = new PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager(ioreactor, connFactory,
            socketFactoryRegistry, new DNSResolverWithCache(dnsCache));
```

I also grep the httpclient httpasynclient httpcore httpcore-nio's source code, only in the DirectByteBufferAllocator has the method allocateDirect (1024).

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: no, finally i use async-http-client instead it